# Speed for the category page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, pagespeed, speedoptimization

Is there any solution to **optimize** the speed for the category page which is having more than 2.5 Lac products in **Magento 2.2.2**?

I have tried to debug the code, I have just put only one attribute `entity_id` in the collection still while I am checking the profiler then it still shows me the class which is being called many times `getAttribute`. Would someone guide me for this if anyone has an idea?

Comment: are you loading 250K products on one page???

Comment: show us the code how you are loading them

Comment: No i am not loading 250k products on single page @MagenX

Comment: I am using default list file to display products. @PhilippSander

Comment: i would upgrade some test environment to magento 2.3.2 and test from there.